# Java enum get string by index

Tags: java, enums

I have enum class like this:

```
REGULARLY("Regularly"),
SOCIALLY("Socially"),
RARELY("Rarely"),
NEVER("Never");

private  final String name;

Drink(String s) {
    name = s;
}
```

How to get value of enum field by its position. For example for position 0 output should be "Regularly". **NOT THE "REGULARLY"**

Comment: Add a getter for the name property, and use `Drink.values()[0].getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get them in order, you can use `Drink.values()`.

Then, you should rename your `name` field to something else, and create a getter for it. (Or keep this name and create a `getName()` getter, but do not use `name()`.)